# Radius of convergence of a power series given by the composition of 2 analityc functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-number-theory

I know that the composition of 2 analytic functions is analytic, and I conjectured that the radius of convergence of the resulting power series should be the smallest of the 2, but I'm not sure and I wouldn't know how to prove that.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you know that the radius of convergence of a series expansion of an analytic function is equal to the distance to the closest pole?

Comment: @Arthur *closest singularity

Comment: @Gary The function $\frac{e^z-1}{z-1}$ has a singularity at $0$ that doesn't in any way affect any radius of convergence. But yes, I guess essential singularities aren't exactly poles per se.

Comment: @Arthur There could, for example, be algebraic singularities or transcendental singularities as well. Consider the power series of $\sqrt{1+z}$ or $\log(1+z)$ about $z=0$. Your example does not have a singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: @Gary Removable singularities are still singularities, and my example has one of those. But I get your point. Singularity is better than pole, although still not perfect without qualification.

Comment: @Arthur Your example does not have a removable singularity at all. Think about it!

Comment: @Gary You're right. It has a pole at $z=1$. I must have meant $\frac{e^z-1}z$.

Comment: We can find a lower bound but in general I don't think we can tell much about the radius of convergence, see how non-trivial it gets with $\exp(\log(1+z))+\exp(2\log(1+z))$

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$
\cosh z = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{z^{2n} }}{{(2n)!}}} 
$$
and
$$
\sqrt {1 + z}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\binom{1/2}{n}z^n } .
$$
Tha radii of convergence is $\infty$ and $1$, respectively. The composition
$$
\cosh \sqrt {1 + z}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(1 + z)^n }}{{(2n)!}}} 
$$
is an entire function, since the series on the right-hand side converges for all complex $z$. Thus the radius of convergence of the power series of $\cosh \sqrt {1 + z}$ at the origin is $+\infty$ and not $1$ as it supposed to be based on your conjecture.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for the counterexample. Do you know if there is anything we could know about the radius of convergence given any 2 power series?

Comment: Let $r>0$ be an arbitrary positive number. Consider $f(z) = \sqrt {1 + z}$ and $g(z) = \frac{1}{r}z$. The radii of convergence of the power series of these functions centered at $z=0$ is $1$ and $+\infty$, respectively. The radius of convergence of the power series of $f(g(z))$ centered at $z=0$ is $r$.